# 2 program get same udp packets from a port

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, pcap

there is a server will send some UDP packets to my localhost, for example: if it send some UDP packets to my localhost and destination port is 5000. and there will have a client program to receive it on port 5000. but, what I want is to create another program, it will try to receive the same packets on port 5000.

if the server send packets p1, p2, p3....pn to my localhost port 5000, I want to both client programs will receive same packets. (client program 1: p1, p2, p3....pn, client program 2: p1, p2, p3...pn)

I tried to use pcap to do this, but seems lost some packets in sometimes.(the server will send some video stream to client)

Comment: `iptables` would do the trick without any extra coding. ask at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use multicast if you want to do this with a single `send` / `sendto` on the server process.  Here are quick examples done in Python 2.7.x for the sake of brevity / reuse of code I had laying around.

It's import for the transmit side to set `IP_MULTICAST_LOOP` if you are going to use this method with transmitter & receivers running on the same host.

sender.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import sys

MCAST_GROUP=sys.argv[1]
MCAST_PORT=int(sys.argv[2])

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, 1 )

for ii in xrange(10):
    msg = 'message %d' %ii
    print 'sending: "%s"'  %msg
    s.sendto( msg, (MCAST_GROUP, MCAST_PORT)
```

receiver.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import socket
import sys
import struct

MCAST_GROUP=sys.argv[1]
MCAST_PORT=int(sys.argv[2])

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1 )
s.bind( (MCAST_GROUP, MCAST_PORT) )

# In C, you'll want to use struct ip_mreq here.  See 'man 7 ip' for details.
# Python's socket module doesn't define a convenient way to do this, hence the
# 'manual' struct.pack
mreq = struct.pack( '4sI', socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GROUP), socket.INADDR_ANY )
s.setsockopt( socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq )

while True:
    rx_data = s.recv(1000)
    print 'received: "%s"' %rx_data
```

Both programs expect two command line arguments, an IPv4 multicast IP (224.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255), and a port.  For example (`./sender.py 239.10.10.10 5000`).

You should be able to run as many instances of `receiver.py` as you like in different terminals, and see that a single instance of `sender.py` will transmit to all receivers.

To translate this to `C`, it's basically:

1. Convert `s = socket.socket(...)` -> `s = socket(...)`
2. Convert `s.X(...)` to `X(s, ...)` for X={`setsockopt`, `bind`, `send`, `recv`}
3. See notes about `ip_mreq`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you read/recv on the socket the messages will be gone from the socket, so even if you use SO_REUSEADDR/ SO_REUSEPORT, I don't think you will be able to read the packets with both clients.

I think the easiest option is to have a local service running on port 5000 which then forwards all packets to the other services. Whether you write that as a server pub/sub style or hard-code it is probably something to decide based on how much effort you want to put into this.